# Structure, Tuple or Dict for the foreach-loop in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I use something akin to the following in tikz?

```
foreach (\x, \y, \colour) in {(0, 0, blue), (1, 1, green)} {
      \node[fill=\colour] at (\x,\y) {};
}
```

Comment: Do you want to have exactly this input syntax or could you live with `\foreach \x/\y/\colour in {0/0/blue, 1/1/green}`? (And I assume that `MyColor` stands for `\colour`?)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, a slightly different syntax is just a good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TikZ itself has a very powerful foreach loop: `\foreach`. (→ [foreach](/questions/tagged/foreach); [PGF manual (v2.10)](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), section 2.20 “Repeating Things: For-Loops” and chapter 56 “Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement”)

It uses the syntax

```
\foreach \varA/\varB/…/\var<N>[<options>] in {val1A/val1B/…/val1<N>,
                                              val2A/val2B/…/val2<N>,
                                               …,
                                              val<m>A/val<m>B/…/val<m><N>}
```

What follows after this is either an argument in braces `{ }` that gets loops over and should use the commands `\varA`, `\varB`, …, `\varN`.
If, as in your example, you only want to loop over one TikZ path you can omit the braces:

```
\tikz
  \foreach \x/\y/\colour in {0/0/blue, 1/1/green}
    \node[fill=\colour] at (\x,\y) {};
```

The optional `<options>` can contain various additional, for example

- `count=\cVar from <C>`: introduces the macro `\cVar` that simply increments from `<C>` through `<C> + <m>`. The `from <C>` part is optional, without it the counter starts at `<C> = 1`.
- `remember=\var as \previousVar (initially <value>)`: can be used to remember a value from the previous iteration under a different name. The `(initially <value>)` is optional.
- `evaluate`: can be used to evaluate a value based on the input variables.

---

If you insist on not using `/` as a delimiter you can create a PGF key with a `.code args` handler where you can specify the exact input syntax and use it then with the `.list` handler. This way any arbitrary delimiters are possible, even mixed ones.

As you use also `,` as a separator in the tuples, you must enbrace those in `{ }` again. You can avoid this by using for examples `;` as the inner separator.

Changing the most outer separator involved a major re-definition of macros. There already exists many other implementation and improvement of such foreach loops.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\tikz
  \foreach \x/\y/\colour in {0/0/blue, 1/1/green}
    \node[fill=\colour] at (\x,\y) {};

\tikz[my Foreach/.code args={(#1,#2,#3)}{\node[fill=#3] at (#1,#2) {};}] {
  \tikzset{my Foreach/.list={{(0, 0, blue)}, {(1, 1, green)}}}
}

\tikz[my Foreach/.code args={#1,#2,#3}{\node[fill=#3] at (#1,#2) {};}] {% same as above
                                                          % but without the parentheses
  \tikzset{my Foreach/.list={{0, 0, blue}, {1, 1, green}}}
}

\tikz[my Foreach/.code args={#1;#2;#3}{\node[fill=#3] at (#1,#2) {};}] {% same as above
                                                              % but with ; instead of ,
  \tikzset{my Foreach/.list={0; 0; blue, 1; 1; green}}
}
\end{document}
```

### Outputs

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The TikZ/PGF kernel has macros for this. I propose a more general `\xforeach` macro written in `expl3`; the syntax is a bit different, but I guess you can live with it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xforeach}{mmm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \unapiedra_xforeach:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \unapiedra_xforeach:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  % store the variables in a sequence
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_unapiedra_variables_seq { , } { #1 }
  % store the data in a sequence
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_unapiedra_data_seq { ; } { #2 }
  % cycle through the data items
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_unapiedra_data_seq
   {
    % separate the items in a sequence
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_unapiedra_instance_seq { , } { ##1 }
    % assign the value to each variable
    \seq_mapthread_function:NNN
      \l_unapiedra_variables_seq
      \l_unapiedra_instance_seq
      \unapiedra_set:Nn
    % execute the code
    #3
   }
 }
% the helper function that does the (temporary) assignments
\cs_new_protected:Npn \unapiedra_set:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_set:Npn #1 { #2 }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_unapiedra_variables_seq
\seq_new:N \l_unapiedra_data_seq
\seq_new:N \l_unapiedra_instance_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \xforeach {\x, \y, \colour} { 0, 0, blue ; 1, 1, green} {
      \node[fill=\colour] at (\x,\y) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]