# Tikz drawing a ring with nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to add the following figure in the presentation of a paper I read. I read a small introduction to tikz but still the figure is very complicated for me to do. Can anybody help or point any guides to help me?

[image: Ring diagram]

Comment: You should work through the tutorials at the start of the TikZ manual. After that, you'll easily draw that figure.

Comment: With what do you have problems? What did you achieve on your own?

Comment: i can do a cyrcle using the "draw controls". But I can't put nodes on it (little black circle that is white inside, I only know the filldraw command. I am currently searching for a faster way to draw a cycle with "draw controls" it is just to painful

Comment: I see that someone has cast a close vote. Please always post a comment explaining why you think a question should be closed (even if it seems obvious to you), and most importantly, explain to the asker what they should do to improve their question. Also, it's best to wait for a while before voting to close a question, to give the asker a chance to react to comments.

Comment: @Paramar: Have you seen the `\foreach` command? That should make it much easier to place the circles automatically, compared to hard-coding them individually. Give that a try, and if you get stuck, edit your question to include the code you have so far, explaining what you've tried and what you're struggling with (at the moment, the question looks a little bit like a "draw-this-for-me" question).

Comment: I got quite the same feeling while reading it again, but believe me this is not my intention at all. I could simply paint it with MS paint and integrate it. My question is more like basic advice over creating some basic figures fast, so that I can afterwards  produce easy figures like this by myself. Of course drawing a part of it for me would help ,cause I would have been able afterwards to "build" on that "working example" the rest by myself. Anyways thanks for your support Jake I will follow your advice

Comment: @Paramar: Some pointers off-hand: You could draw a full circle then place the nodes along it with `\foreach` (this should be quite easy to do). As for the black dot inside the white circle, that's possible with a simple `fill`, no trickery needed, like so: `\draw [fill=black] (36:5cm) circle (1mm);` (here the circle with the nodes has a radius of 5 cm and the first small circle at 36 deg, if we have 10 along the whole circle, so I center the dot in the small circle; the 1mm radius of the dot can be adjusted at will - maybe not the most elegant, but a simple, straightforward solution).

Comment: So what's the point of asking the OP to show the work he(she has done, and saying not to ask "do this for me" questions", and voting for closing this kind of questions if in the end the code is gonna be delivered?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Are you implying we should not tell people these things anymore?

Comment: @Jake No; I'm just saying that I see little point in telling all that about "show your efforts", "don't ask questions like that", and then, without waiting for the OP to show his/her work, providing an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, let’s work it through.

I used the `through` library because we can simply use the anchors of the node as a reference and don’t have to worry where the circle exactly is in our picture.

#### Styles

I defined three styles:

- the `dot node` style is for the simple nodes on the circle, I have used `fill=white` so that the circle is not seen in the circle. This works best with a simple background.
- the `dotdot node` inherits the `dot node` style but also places a filled dot inside it (disguised as a label).
- the `arc style` is for the arc arrows in the circle, the shorten amount is needed so that the `|` part of the arrow overlap for connecting arrows. For more discussion and other solutions on that matter, see [TikZ arrow tip is displaced](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111051/16595)

The `dotdot node` style expects two mandatory arguments. The one is used to name the node, the second is used for any options for the label. We use this later to place a pin at the label (the black dot in the node).

#### TikZ picture options

The options to the `tikzpicture` are:

- `thick`,
- `every ping edge/.style={<-}` which sets the arrow style for the pins. If you use other pins in your code, you will need to change this and declare a separate style that is used for the pin edge.
- `>=latex` sets the default arrow for the `>` arrow tip. I don’t like the `to` style much so I set `latex` here.

The following `declare function` is used to declare some constants (the outer radius and the inner radius for the circle and the arrow arcs) and a function `angleofNode` that takes on argument, the number of the node. As we place 23 nodes, this function easily calculates the angle on a circle.

We could have used also LaTeX macros, i.e.

```
\newcommand*{\outerR}{4}
\newcommand*{\innerR}{3.3}
\newcommand*{\angleofNode}[1]{(#1)/23*360}
```

and could have used these macro instead of the PGF math functions.

#### Drawing

The outer circle is easy. The `circle through` key from the `through` library is used to easily draw the circle. We name the node `c` for the next steps.

The points on the circle are now accessible by `c.east`, `c.30`, `c.170`, etc. We use this to place our simple `dot node`s there. The `\foreach` loop can be used to draw a bunch of nodes.

Another `\foreach` loop is used to draw the `dotdot node`s. In this same step we also draw the labels `A_{<something>}`, name the `dotdot node`s `dd-<number>` and also the black dots inside the `dotdot node`s. These are named `ddd-<number>`, this is done by the first argument to the `dotdot node` style. The second argument is used to for the `pin` with the text `T_{<something>}`.

In bot cases `<something>` is the macro `\tLabel` which we have declared for every step in the loop with the second value. The directions for the label and the pins are also defined in the loop. The `\foreach` loop from TikZ is very powerful and has its own tag [foreach](/questions/tagged/foreach). A short introduction can be found in [Structure, Tuple or Dict for the foreach-loop in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119391/16595).

The third and final `\foreach` loop is used to draw the arcs. Now, this is not that easy as we don’t have a circle to reference. Even if we had, we would have to draw the arc ourself.

The `arc` path operator does not draw an arc from one point to another with a specified radius. It draws an arc from the last point on the path with a radius, a certain start and a certain end angle. (There is also `delta angle` for when you only have one of the other angles.)

So, we need to move to one of the points on the arc: `({angleofNode(\sAngle)}:innerR)`. Then we draw an `arc` with the radius of `innerR` from the node `\sAngle` to `\eAngle`. Again, the `angleofNode(<node number>)` function helps us to find the correct angle. Unfortunately, the placement of nodes along of `arc`s is non-function (in the current release version of TikZ anyway), so I also place the node manually halfway along the path but `.3cm` to the center. This has been discussed before in [How to place a node in the middle of an arc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38763/16595).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through,arrows}
\tikzset{
  dot node/.style={
    shape=circle,
    fill=white,
    draw,
    inner sep=+0pt,
    minimum size=+5mm
  },
  dotdot node/.style 2 args={
    dot node,
    label={[shape=circle,fill=black,outer sep=+0pt,inner sep=+0pt,minimum size=+3mm,name=ddd-#1,#2]center:}
  },
  arc style/.style={
    |<->|,
    shorten >=+-.5\pgflinewidth,
    shorten <=+-.5\pgflinewidth,
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  thick,
  every pin edge/.style={<-},
  >=latex,
  declare function/.list={
    outerR=4;,
    innerR=3.3;,
    angleofNode(\a)=\a/23*360;}
  ]
  \node [draw,circle through=(0:outerR)] (c) {};

  \foreach \iAngle in {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,...,14,16,17,19,20,...,22}
    \node[dot node] at (c.{angleofNode(\iAngle)}) {};

  \foreach \iAngle/\tLabel/\lDir/\pDir in {0/3/above right/-10,%
                                           3/2/above right/right,%
                                           6/1/above/30,%
                                           9/k/above left/above,%
                                           15/l+1/below/left,%
                                           18/l/below right/below}
    \node[
      dotdot node=\iAngle{pin={\pDir:{$T_{\tLabel}$}}},
      label=\lDir:$A_{\tLabel}$
    ] (dd-\iAngle) at (c.{angleofNode(\iAngle)}) {};

  \foreach \sAngle/\eAngle/\tLabel in {0/3/2,%
                                       3/6/1,%
                                       6/9/k,%
                                       15/18/l}
    \draw[arc style] ({angleofNode(\sAngle)}:innerR) arc[radius=innerR, start angle=angleofNode(\sAngle), end angle=angleofNode(\eAngle)]
         node at ({angleofNode(\sAngle+\eAngle)/2}:innerR-.3) {$S_{\tLabel}$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Your pun did not go unnoticed.  Nice explanation!!

Answer (score 7):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}

\newcommand\MAL[4][1.5]{% Middle Arc Label
    \rput(!#1 N-#3.y N-#3.x atan N-#2.y N-#2.x atan add 2 div PtoC){$#4$}}

\newcommand\NL[6][]{% Node Label
    \qdisk(#2){3pt}
    \uput{12pt}[#4](#2){$#3$}
    \ifx\\#1\\%
        \def\name{#5}
    \else
        \def\name{#1}
    \fi
    \uput{17pt}[#6](#2){\rnode{\name}{$#5$}}
    \pcline[nodesepB=3pt,nodesepA=7pt]{->}(\name)(#2)}

\everypsbox{\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(6,4)
    % Big circle
    \pscircle{2.5}
    % Node declaration
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=24]{0}{360}{2.5 t PtoC}{P}
    % Small  circles
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\pscircle[fillstyle=solid](P\i){5pt}}
    % Arcs
    \begingroup
        \psset{arrows=|<*->|*}
        \psarc(0,0){2}{(P0)}{(P3)}
        \psarc(0,0){2}{(P3)}{(P6)}
        \psarc(0,0){2}{(P6)}{(P9)}
        \psarc(0,0){2}{(P15)}{(P18)}
    \endgroup
    % Middle Arc Labels
    \MAL{P0}{P3}{S_2}
    \MAL{P3}{P6}{S_1}
    \MAL{P6}{P9}{S_k}
    \MAL{P15}{P18}{S_l}
    % Node Labels
    \NL{P0}{A_3}{15}{T_3}{-15}
    \NL{P3}{A_2}{45}{T_2}{0}
    \NL{P6}{A_1}{90}{T_1}{45}
    \NL{P9}{A_k}{135}{T_k}{90}
    \NL[TL1]{P15}{A_{l+1}}{-90}{T_{l+1}}{180}
    \NL{P18}{A_l}{-45}{T_l}{-90}
    % Others
    \psarcn{->}{3.75}{35}{-20}
    \uput{4}[7.5](0,0){\parbox{2cm}{\scriptsize Traverse\\Direction}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]