# Defining a command with arbitrary number of parameters

Tags: macros

I've done a few searches, and found possible solutions to my question. However, those that I saw were somehow more complicated than what I think I really need. So please excuse me for asking again. Here's the scenario:

I want to define a math command that gives the long exact sequence of the given parameters. So for example, if I write `\longexactsequence{A}{B}{C}{D}` then I expect to have something like `0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow D \longrightarrow 0`.

Similarly, if I just write `\longexactsequence{A}`, then I would just get `0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow 0`.

How can I do this? I'm also pushing this one step further, as I would doubly appreciate a "fix" for breaking the line if the output equation is already too long.

Thanks a lot, and all comments, hints, etc would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This can be done using `\@ifnextchar\bgroup`. It may be easier and more robust to simply use a `,` to separate the entries: `\longexactsequence{A,B,C,D}`.

Comment: Hi there. Actually, it makes more sense to follow your suggestion. I'm now searching for this. Thanks! =)

Comment: Following @Qrrbrbirlbel's suggestion of using a CSV list, your could just use solutions from [Iterating through comma-separated arguments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87407/5764).

Comment: Following u/Qrrbrbirlbel's answer, I went a bit further and tried to 'better' it; I needed some assistance to complete it and u/egreg's came up with a wonderful solution that stays true to the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683442/290450 . Hope you find it useful as well!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*An implementation using `\kernel@ifnextchar` for an input syntax like `\longexactsequence{A}{B}{C}{D}` and an implementation using LaTeX’s `\@for` macro for an input syntax like `\longexactsequence{A, B, C, D}` can be found in [the history of this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/126115/3).*

When you want to use `,` as a separator for the entries, you can use one of many packages that provide loops. One of this is the [quite powerful `\foreach` macro of PGF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119391/16595), it has its own tag: [foreach](/questions/tagged/foreach).

If you want to apply a second value for a superscript of the arrow you can use `\foreach`, too, but need to use `/` for the delimiter of those arguments.

An arrow that should not be labeled need to be input as `/<entry>`.

There are other ways to input this, say

```
$ \longexactsequence{[f]A, [g]B, C} $
```

making the arrow label optional but this will need a more sophisticated implementation.

A poor man’s version of this has been implemented by using `\ifx` that checks whether both following macros are equal (which `\superscript` and `\entry` are if you don’t provide the `/`). This can be surpassed by adding another space (`D/ D`), an empty group (`D{}/D`) or `\relax` (`D\relax/D`) in one of both parameters.

The examples should show this clearly.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{extarrows,pgffor}
\newcommand*{\longexactsequence}[2][0]{%
  #1 \longrightarrow
  \foreach \superscript/\entry in {#2} {%
    \entry \xlongrightarrow{\ifx\superscript\entry\else\superscript\fi}%
  } #1%
}

\begin{document}
$ \longexactsequence{A, B, C, D, E} $

$ \longexactsequence{f/A, g/B, C, D/ D} $ % a space before or after / makes the Ds unequal

$ \longexactsequence[Z]{a/A, {a, b}/B} $

$ \longexactsequence{} $
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Great! With your explanation, it becomes clear now. I really appreciate this! Thanks! =)

Comment: @Eric The `[2][0]` specify for the definition of `\longexactsequence` that it takes two (`2`) arguments, the second pair of brackets imply that the first of those two arguments is optional, the default value is `0`. In the **A** implementation you cannot have `0 → 0` (if this is allowed at all). The **B** one survives an empty argument (`\longexactsequence{}`) and prints correctly `0 → 0`. If an empty set is to be accepted often, one can change the definition of **A** easily, if needed.

Comment: @Eric Though, in the end I recommend **B** and even more so **C** because you can quite easily create and customize loops (there are a lot of packages and tools for looping in LaTeX, PGF’s `\foreach` is simply the one I am most comfortable with), the implementation is also the shortest.

Comment: I prefer Code B more for my needs. Also, I don't think I would be having `0 \longrightarrow 0`.
Last question, is there a way for the `\@for` to take two parameters at a time? I mean, I wanted to extend this code to have something like `\longexactsequence{A,B}{f,g}` to mean `0\longrightarrow A \xlongrightarrow{f} B \xlongrightarrow{g} 0`?

(I am really a newbie to latex codes.)

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. Code C may be more newbie-friendly, i.e. more suitable for me...

Comment: @Eric Would you be willing to accept an input like `\longexactsequence{f/A,g/B}` or `\longexactsequence{[f]A,[g]B}`. There are quite a few options to do this. Combining those two things from two sets make things a little bit more complicated (but everything’s solvable in the end). Does every arrow has a label?

Comment: Not every arrow has a label. But I thought, I would just put `{}` for an empty label. I don't mind the syntax of how to write them. so `f/A` is not a problem for me!

Comment: I already got it! Thanks again! I'm now able to do what I just described. =D

Comment: @Eric Congratulations! Nevertheless, I have updated and cleaned up my answer to show you the easiest `\foreach` implementation I could think of.

Answer (score 4):

The `\getargsC` macro parses a single argument into "words" that are placed in `\argi`, `\argii`, `\argiii`, `\argiv`, etc. The total number of words are set in the string `\narg`.  A word with spaces or ending in a macro, can be isolated by surrounding it in braces (i.e., the contents of the inner braces becomes a word.  Then I just regurgitate the words one by one, with the proper decorations surrounding them.

In the loop, `\csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname` just becomes successive arguments (`\argi`, `\argii`, `\argiii`, `\argiv`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand\longexactsequence[1]{%
  \getargsC{#1}%
  0\longrightarrow%
  \setcounter{index}{0}
  \whiledo{\value{index} < \narg}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname\longrightarrow%
  }
  0%
}
\begin{document}
\(
\longexactsequence{A B C D}
\)

To show with other than simple characters

\(
\longexactsequence{A_1 {\alpha} {B + C}}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm voting for this answer and not the other one because it uses code that hides kernel internals from the innocent.

Comment: Thanks! I have to admit though that it would take me more time to study and understand what's happening here. =)

Comment: @eric I just added a short explanation.

Comment: But can this solution handle two sequences of arguments, similar to how the accepted solution can?

Comment: @user89 As is, no it cannot.  However, the `listofitems` package, from which the `readarray` package draws, can do what you ask in a quite straightforward manner.  If I get a chance, I might try to work something up.