# foreach-loop in align

Tags: foreach

I want to write a macro for optimisation problems and my current approach is to write a macro, that takes the target function and a list of constraints.
The entries are separated by comma, and each entry is of the type "(in)equality / range", e.g.

```
x_i \geq 0 / i=1,...,n
```

I got the idea from [Defining a command with arbitrary number of parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126114/defining-a-command-with-arbitrary-number-of-parameters).
However, this does not allow new lines inside an align.

My friend found out to use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, but now I cannot write `&` inside the loop.
The following code compiles, but does not look nice.

**edit:** now has entries of type `\x/\y`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{extarrows,pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x/\y in {a/3, b/5, foo/0}{
      \x_i : \x = \x \quad i=\y \\
    }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if I replace the body of the loop by `\x_i : \x &= \x \quad i=\y \\` (just adding the `&`), I get multiple errors `! Undefined control sequence.

Furthermore, using entry `a/{0,\ldots,5}` does not work as expected.
It only takes the `0`.

Also I might wish to put the range of my variable inside `\tag`, or similar.
Tying this, I get another `Undefined control sequence` for `\y¸.

- So how can I align these lines inside the loop? **solved in answer of Steven B. Segletes**
- How can I have more complex values in the entries?
- How can I place the second part of an entry inside `\tag*{}`?

Maybe-helpful-link: I don't understand [Foreach loop in tabular, missing endgroup inserted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309765/foreach-loop-in-tabular-missing-endgroup-inserted), so I can't tell, whether the idea helps, but it seems to go in the direction.

Comment: This is a well-known problem with active characters: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227084/appending-active-and-expansion-sensitive-characters-to-a-macro

Comment: Would you please make a more sensible example based on what you actually want to achieve (the inequalities, I guess)? The example you give is a typical XY-problem.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I was too focused on the alignment. I have adjusted my example and extended my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fairly general macro that takes four mandatory arguments and one optional as described in the code.

The idea is to define a scheme for the input, in the examples it is `#1/#2`, but it can be whatever with any number of arguments (up to nine, of course); we also define the template for each row, using `#1` and so on for the actual arguments to be substituted; finally, the input. The optional argument is for accommodating `alignat` or `alignedat` that need to know the number of column pairs to be typeset.

An internal function is defined to deliver the required template; then it is a matter of splitting the input at commas and feed each item to the template function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makealignment}{mommm}
 { % #1 = environment
   % #2 = optional for alignat
   % #3 = scheme for the variables
   % #4 = scheme for the rows
   % #5 = items
   \cs_set_protected:Npn \__hennich_row:w #3 \q_stop { #4 }
   \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__hennich_input_seq { , } { #5 }
   \seq_set_map:NNn
     \l__hennich_output_seq
     \l__hennich_input_seq
     { \__hennich_row:n { ##1 } }
   \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\begin{#1}}{\begin{#1}{#2}}
   \seq_use:Nn \l__hennich_output_seq { \\ }
   \end{#1}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__hennich_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l__hennich_output_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hennich_row:n { \__hennich_row:w #1 \q_stop }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\makealignment{align*}
  {#1/#2}
  {#1_{i} : #1 &= #1 & i&=#2}
  {a/3, b/5, foo/0}

\makealignment{alignat}[2]
  {#1/#2}
  {#1_{i} : #1 &= #1 &\qquad i&=#2}
  {a/3, b/5, foo/0}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here I build a token list, and then pass it to `align*`.  The use of `\xaddtotoks` allows the first token in the list (here `\x`) to be expanded once in the building of the token list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,amsmath}
\newtoks\alignbuild
\newcommand{\addtotoks}[2]{#1\expandafter{\the#1#2}}
\newcommand{\xaddtotoks}[2]{\expandafter\addtotoks\expandafter#1\expandafter{#2}}
\begin{document}
\readlist\mylist{1,2,3,666}
\foreachitem\x\in\mylist{%
  \xaddtotoks\alignbuild{\x : }%
  \xaddtotoks\alignbuild{\x &= }%
  \xaddtotoks\alignbuild{\x\\}%
}
\def\tmp{\begin{align*}}
\expandafter\tmp\the\alignbuild
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]