# Tikz \foreach to work with the aligned environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, foreach

I am trying to use the `\foreach` command to create something with the same effect as:

```
\begin{align*}
   1 \\
   2
\end{align*}
```

The following code fails to work:

```
\begin{align*}
  \foreach \x in {1,2} {
    \x \\
  }
\end{align*}
```

The error message reads as follows:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

I tried to do some research but cannot find anything useful (to me), so any suggestion or advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Unfortunately this is not that simple, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439912/121799.

Comment: @marmot Oh, I was not aware of the question that you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These things are tricky because of expansion issues, see the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439912/121799). These answers suggest to load more packages and abandon `\foreach`. Of course, if you do not insist on `\foreach` you could just do it without packages and use a recursion to do the loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{pft}
\def\pftloop{\stepcounter{pft}  \number\value{pft}\\ \ifnum\number\value{pft}<2
\pftloop\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\setcounter{pft}{0}\pftloop
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More complex examples work, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{pft}
\newcounter{sum}
\def\pftloop{\stepcounter{pft} \setcounter{sum}{\number\value{pft}} 
\number\value{pft}+\stepcounter{pft}\number\value{pft}
\addtocounter{sum}{\number\value{pft}}
&=\number\value{sum}\\ \ifnum\number\value{pft}<9
\pftloop\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\setcounter{pft}{0}\pftloop
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. As you guessed, I simply want a loop in an aligned environment, and your method seems to do the trick.